# Looking for non-gui utility application

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

I'm searching for application (if exists). It should appear after pressing previously customized keys, and will have non-gui (aka command shell) (but it should be have 'buttons' like in GRUB 2), it should have some utilities like task manager, etc. It will be helpful when game crashed, and I can't move cursor, so I can't do anything (except Alt+Tab (but i can't do anything more after that) and resetting my computer).

I'm writing this 2nd time because I accidenly pressed 'back' button on my mouse. But Firefox is a crap, and after forwarding, my whole text dissapear lol.

Comment: Have you ever thought of going to the virtual terminal: `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`-`F6`? You'll then have a full working terminal at hand. Go back with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7` (or `F8`/`F9` in some configurations) :) Pro tip: [How can I use the mouse in a virtual terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/q/245948/88802)

Comment: and how I can't exit that to desktop? Therefore I'm looking for user friendly application.

Comment: "and how I can't exit that to desktop?" Sorry, what? Please be specific in your requirements - *edit* your question to include more details if so.

Comment: OK, so basicly i'm in this virtual terminal, but to kill process i need a ID. And really isn't there available application like I mentioned before?

Comment: If the motivation is to recover a locked up screen due to a game gone bad, consider this ctrl+alt+backspace.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XorgCtrlAltBackspace.  You might need to re-enable it as it's disabled in 13.04 by default.

Comment: Well, just use `top` to kill the application or any other tool to do that. You could also use `pkill` if you know the name of the process. Either way, this is not a full answer - I would love to provide one - but it's unclear what your exact requirements are. And again: please *edit* your question to include the details - this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @MattH But then the desktop session is destroyed. ;) I assume that OP is just looking for a way to kill the crashed game.

Comment: KDE has Ctrl + Alt + Esc that turns the mouse cursor into a skull. Clicking on a window will kill it. Press Esc again if you decide not to kill anything.

Answer (score 0):

A full command line interface environment can be achieved by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-F6</kbd> in Ubuntu.

You can try using [General Purpose Mouse interface](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpm/) to simulate a cursor in your command line interface.

If you are looking for a command-line browser I would suggest you look into [Links](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/links).