# Mouse Pointer in tty terminal

Tags: 13.04, mouse, tty

Good evening,

just experienced a funny bug (?):

When I switch to tty terminal, my mouse pointer still appears, but is in the center of the screen. When I switch back into graphical mode, the pointer is on the same position as when I switched to terminal mode.

Course, this is not sore, but it's strange!

Did someone experienced it before? I do just after the latest updates…

Does anyone know against which package to file a bug in Launchpad?

Thanks ;)

---

System spec:

- Kernel

  ```
  Linux 3.8.0-27-generic x86_64
  ```
- Graphic card:

  ```
  VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780M [Mobility Radeon
  ```

  HD 3200] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
- Driver (output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 AMD`):

  ```
  01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200] [1002:9612]
  Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ffb0]
  Kernel driver in use: radeon
  ```

Comment: What graphics card and kernel are you using? I guess this has to do with kernel mode setting and the cursor interaction with the driver. By the way, it's also possible to use the mouse pointer in a TTY: [How can I use the mouse in a virtual terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/q/245948/88802)

Comment: My kernel: `Linux 3.8.0-27-generic x86_64` ; My graphic card: `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include more details - it is how this site works. Please also include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 AMD` to include which driver you're on.

Comment: I did it and added the spec…

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, file a bug against `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` in Launchpad.