# Cannot open Gnome-Terminal Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome-terminal, 17.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 from 17.04, I have been unable to launch gnome-terminal.
Upon clicking terminal icon, the taskbar shows terminal loading bar but then disappears after a few seconds.

Terminal loading in the taskbar:

[image]

I have tried the following:

- Purged and Re-installed gnome-terminal
- `sudo apt-get autoremove` and fix-missing
- Changed locale to `en_US` in `/etc/default/locale`

I am able to access xterm and running *gnome-terminal* returns the following:

```
No protocol specified  
Unable to init server: Could not connect:
Connection refused   
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Searching the error gives results solving terminal access issues over an ssh connection which is not my case.

How do I fix this and get gnome-terminal running?

Comment: A work-around is to install another terminal emulator. There are many, that are on par with `gnome-terminal`. Some are lighter, some are more powerful. Do you want tips about suitable candidates?

Comment: @sudodus Yeah sure! Xterm doesn't let me use copy-paste shortcuts. Anything that does will be handy

Comment: `lxterminal` and `sakura` are light, `xfce4-terminal` is medium (comes with Xubuntu), `tilda` has special features ..., I have read about `terminator` but not used it. -- But you *can* mark and paste with `xterm` according to this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/961175/copy-and-paste-doesnt-work-in-the-terminal/961226#961226

Comment: I have installed Terminator which works good. It does support copy-paste . Thanks for the suggestions. @sudodus

Comment: I think you might stay with `terminator` :-)

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ#Terminal_fails_to_start might help you.

Comment: If you found this Q while trying to get gnome-terminal to run in WSL, try this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1556456/414476

Answer (score 1):

I has the same problem but with file-roller and follow this  [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi).

You have to change this file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (with root permissions).
Just add

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

After saving the file, initialize a new terminal or reboot the system.

Comment: I tried this method and reinstalled gnome-terminal. Checked sshd_config and it already has X11Forwarding set as yes. So the solution doesn't work for me. I guess I will just continue using terminator for now. Thank you for your answer @Santoja . If the answer does help someone, let me know, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed new python 3.5 env you are unable to open `gnome-terminal`. Use the following commands:

1. `sudo rm /usr/bin/python3`
2. `sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3`