# Unable to connect via Ethernet

Tags: ethernet

I cannot get on the internet in Ubuntu when I connect via Ethernet.

In Windows it works just fine, so it’s an Ubuntu issue. I also get this when running lshw -c network.

[image]

How do I resolve this? Is this a driver issue with RTL8168?

When I run `sudo modprobe r8169` I get
`modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic`

And when I try `sudo dimes | grep r816` I see nothing.

Comment: Please don't put pictures and screenshots of the terminal. Always copy the output of the terminal and paste it directly in your question, and then format the pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the [edit question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1354403/edit) window. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961175/copy-and-paste-doesnt-work-in-the-terminal) for how to copy the output from the terminal.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169`

Comment: modprobe r8169 didn’t find anything.

Comment: So now when you run: `sudo lshw -C network` is your ethernet still shown as UNCLAIMED? If not, does Network Manager offer to connect? Are there any clues in the log? `sudo dmesg | grep r816` Please edit your question to show the result.

Comment: Still shows as unclaimed.

Comment: Ah, haa! Now may we see: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: So I just installed r8168-dkms along with linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) as well. Says there's an issue with virtualbox-dkms but I have ethernet back now.

Comment: Why did I need linux-modules-extra for this to work?

Comment: It is required and was probably not installed properly. It provides ethernet and wireless drivers, among many others.