# Select all text on current line

Tags: shortcut-keys

I know <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. But I want to select all text on the current line where the cursor is.  I don't want to move the cursor to the beginning or the end of the line to do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>.

What shortcut key do people use if they want to select all text on current line?

Comment: Double-click selects the word under the cursor. **Triple-click selects the line under the cursor.** You paste it with a single middleclick. Find more details at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961175/copy-and-paste-doesnt-work-in-the-terminal/961226#961226)

Comment: Is there a shortcut key without click?

Comment: In which tools do you want to do this? Text or graphics user interface?

Comment: mostly browser - firefox.

Comment: I don't know any better method than those already mentioned by you and me. If you are lucky, someone will chip in and give you what you want.

Comment: @sudodus : triple-clic on the line ?

Comment: @cmak.fr, Yes, triple-clic (the left button) on the line. Try it. If the line is longer (and folded because the width of the box is too narrow for it), the whole line will be selected (high-lighted). This happens with comments here.